# Is floating point IEEE754 binary digit represented using special unit/circuit for arithmetic operation?

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, computer-architecture, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

We know that two un/signed integers arithmetic operation using special circuit called full-adder to execute arithmetic operation in Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU).

The full-adder I mean is classical adder that consist with two half-adder cascaded and an OR-GATE. It has Cin, A, B, S, and Cout pin.

How about two float numbers that represented with IEEE754 standard when doing arithmetic operation? Will the operation using full-adder which same like un/signed integer arithmetic operation uses or.. it will using antoher special circuit?

I think it will using another special unit to operate floating number arithmetic operation that ofcourse consisted with another logic gates since it's not compatible with classical full-adder for integer.

Note that, I'm talking about abstract circuit (logic gates/ALU/full-adder) not physical circuit such as transistor, ground, power, etc.

Comment: FP addition and subtraction requires some kind of barrel shifter, one that also tracks the number of required shifts, for the mantissa. That's not in the usual integer ALU repertoire. (Fully combinatorial versions have been made in the past -- Bipolar Integrated Technologies, for example.)

Comment: What kind of an answer are you looking for, here? As written, a simple "yes" seems to suffice.

Comment: @TimWilliams I know how IEEE754 represented and I know what happen when computer doing addition/substraction for integer. But I don't know what happened when two float numbers doing addition/subtraction. For example `2.71 + 3.14`, what happened at there? I think computer will decode the operands (2.71 and 3.14) to the IEEE754 format in binary as the first step.

Comment: When you say "2.71 + 3.14", do you mean literally this string representation, and how a programming language interprets that as a number? Or do you mean the floating point values (0x402d70a4 and 0x4048f5c3) and the logic function to sum them?

Comment: @Muhammad There will be an ASCII parser that parses the number formats. In the process, this parser will generate the FP result either by doing it in still more software (which is easy to do without the use of any FP hardware at all) or by using FP hardware should it also exist. Once the two numbers are converted, the FP ADD (for example), will unpack the mantissa and exponent and sign and hidden bit and perform stuff that is more than most will want to write about here (in general form, anyway, as it would require a chapter or two.)

Comment: @TimWilliams 0x402d70a4 and 0x4048f5c3 is what I mean. As you see if we just add that numbers with classical adder, it will return 0x80766667 (-1.0873323585885238e-38) where it doesn't equal with 5.85

Comment: @periblepsis after they are unpacked, will one of unpacked bits (mantissa/exponent/sign) use classical full-adder?

Comment: If depends on computer. And the program. If you just type in "2.71" + "3.14", who says they need to be even floating point numbers in any stage? Your program may store it it as a string and do the addition one digit at a time just like you do on pen and paper. However, if you do add "17.42" to "3.4" the computer will have to do the exact same steps you would do on pen and paper to get the correct answer - or in the case of floating point, a close enough approximation as not all decimal numbers can be exactly represented in floating point.

Comment: The FPU is designed to do the needful for floating point numbers just like the ALU does the needful for integers. With floating point, the needful is more complicated. Of course it is a different circuit because it does something different. It is still made out of logic gates. Because part of the algorithm is addition and subtraction etc it will surely use full adders to do the addition and subtraction, shifters to do shifting, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Floating point addition requires mantissa alignment before the add, a shift to align the binary points.

In the case of IEEE754 representation, the adder has to handle the fact that the MSB is implied, not present. This can either be done by inserting an MSB of '1' before a normal adder, or using a special adder which acts as if this has been done.

The insertion of an implied MSB does not apply for denormalised numbers of course, signalled by the exponent under-flowing.

This means that a floating point adder to IEEE754 must do something 'special' above using just a full adder, if it is to do what is specified.

How it does that special stuff, whether it's all encoded in a single cycle of hardware, or whether it takes several microcoded steps, is up to the designer of the chip. It's simply a speed/cost tradeoff.